# Generating random two digit hex values

Tags: android

I am developing an app for android and in this app i want to generate two random two digit hex values like:
1. two digit random hex value (ex. AA, 3A, 4E...)
2. two digit random even hex value (ex. 12, 1A... not 13, 35, 1B, 2D...)

and set them to textviews.

Setting to textview easy, but i couldn't find a way to generate a two digit random even hex number.

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the actual android API, but you could (respectively the two cases you mentioned):

1. generate a random integer number between 0 and 255;
2. generate a random integer number between 0 and 127 and multiply it by two;

and then print them in hexadecimal format.

Comment: I am stupid for not thinking that easy solution.. for my case it has to be two digit so my generated integers starts from 16. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Just generate a random integer and convert it to hexadecimal:

```
Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
int x = rnd.nextInt(256); //Between 0-255
String hex = Integer.toHexString(x);
```

If you need to make sure it's even, just check whether `x % 2 == 0`.